# Como solucionar error "No se puede establecer una relación de confianza para el canal seguro SSL/TLS."

Tags: vb.net

tengo un codigo en VB.net que quiere descargar una imagen desde una dirección web.
La plataforma es Netframework 4.5

```
Try
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim lafoto As HttpWebRequest
        Dim respuesta As HttpWebResponse
        lafoto = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://172.30.25.36/video1.jpg")
        lafoto.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        respuesta = lafoto.GetResponse
        Dim imagen As Image = Image.FromStream(respuesta.GetResponseStream)
        imagen.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\a.jpg")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim imagen As Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\nodisponible.jpg")
        imagen.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\a.jpg")
    End Try
```

Comment: y cual es el problema???

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado

```
  Try

        Dim lafoto As HttpWebRequest
        Dim respuesta As HttpWebResponse
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors)
                                                                                 Return True
                                                                             End Function
        lafoto = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://172.30.25.36/video1.jpg")
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        lafoto.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
                                                                                 respuesta = lafoto.GetResponse
                                                                                 Dim imagen As Image = Image.FromStream(respuesta.GetResponseStream)
                                                                                 imagen.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\a.jpg")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim imagen As Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\nodisponible.jpg")
        imagen.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\a.jpg")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Colocar las siguientes 2 líneas antes de la invocación al servicio

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```